# Set an Internet protocol for a specific browser

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, inno-setup

Let me ask you a difficult question:

I should have the possibility to open only HTTPS sites with Internet explorer. I wonder if there is a procedure to check into the operating system which browser is the default one and behave differently as follows:

1)  If internet explorer is the default one just say something like “your default browser is Internet Explorer. The procedure will finish” and then exit;

2)  If Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome is the default one  the script should change into the registry the references only for HTTPS in order to have Internet explorer run only HTTPS sites and then display something like “Associations have been set. Press a button to finish” and exit;

3)  Last but not least I wonder whether there is a way to avoid Chrome or Firefox display (if they are preferred browsers and after changing HTTPS association for Internet Explorer) the warning to set them again as default browser (i.e. I would like to leave them opening all other sits but HTTPS);

Do you think it is possible to do this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Meleena

Comment: While it's not impossible to do this sort of thing, it's generally better to ensure that sites work with all browsers.  It may not be a big problem if this is for something limited-use (eg a bespoke app) but in general users will be confused and annoyed if certain links mysteriously divert to a different browser.  In addition, note that changing the OS associations will only affect links accessed outside of the web browser itself -- eg. someone clicking an HTTPS link within Chrome will still open using Chrome itself, no matter what you do.

Comment: the key to for preferred browser is:

hkey_current_user\software\clients\startmenuinternet

I do not know how to tell via batch file something like:

if "hkey_current_user\software\clients\startmenuinternet" = Iexplore.exe do nothing 

if "hkey_current_user\software\clients\startmenuinternet" = 
Chrome.exe or Firefox.exe then

reg add 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Roaming\OpenWith\UrlAssociations\https\Userchoice]
(ProgId) "IE.HTTPS"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\https\DefaultIcon]
(Default) iexplore.exe,-1003

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\https\Shell\Open\Command]
(Default) iexplore.exe %1

Comment: @Miral: you are right unfortunately the https web page runs an ActiveX so i am obliged to split https for iexplore and http for other browsers (if iexplore.exe is not the default one)

Comment: How is the user actually loading the page?  If they're clicking a desktop or start menu shortcut then you can force this to load using `iexplore` without redirecting all of `https`.  If they're using a menu item within your application you can do the same thing.

Comment: @Miral: user runs the https web page from a shortcut.In any case as we saw in windows 8 and 8.1 we were unable to assign https only to a browser we changed our mind and have always IE work with them.Better for end users as well.Thanks again. Meleena

Comment: In W7, W8 (probably also Vista) in "default programs", "set associations" http and https can be individually assigned to different programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user is running the page from a shortcut, simply define the shortcut like so:

```
[Icons]
Name: {group}\MyApp Website; Filename: iexplore.exe; Parameters: https://your.website.com/; Flags: useapppaths
```

You may also wish to add an `IconFilename` to give it a custom icon.